# SVN client authentication error

Tags: svn

I have the following error when ever I try to connect to a SVN server on my network:

> Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge

Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to be more accurate with the information. What svn client you use, what svn server, on what OS are you trying (client / server) and so on if you want accurate answers

Answer (score 6):

rm ~/.gnome2/keyrings/login.keyring
helped me.... afterwards I had to re-enter my password when checking out with
svn checkout -username tom https://servername.domain/

Comment: +1, your answer helped me too.

Answer (score 1):

You've got bad credentials in your http(s) svn url.  The error message is telling you that it's trying to use http [Basic Auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) and failing.

Answer (score 1):

follow these steps if you are facing this issue(on ubuntu)

1. type this command: `svn ls http://[subversionpath]` ,it will ask for authentication. enter you password if promoted for
2. type ant command

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
password-stores = #intentionally left blank
```

in your `~/.subversion/config` file eventually combined with `--non-interactive --trust-server-cert` args to the subversion command to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and in fact it results in the point, that SVN doesn't save your login information locally.

I was able to fix this problem by doing the following steps:

1.) I edited my SVN config like this:

```
`store-passwords = yes`
`store-auth-creds = yes`
```

2.)

```
svn ls REPOSITORY_PATH
```

using my correct user data.

After this procedure SVN has stored your login data locally. This fixed my problems.

Have a nice day!